# Bash Script: how to pass arguments to a function of a running script from another one?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to call a function of a running script from another, and then pass to it an argument (in runtime)

// Original script

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE_OF_EXIT_CODE=256

/bin/bash /home/dev/runningScript.sh arg1 arg2

# some code
doSomething ($VALUE_OF_EXIT_CODE)
```

// running script

```
#!/bin/bash

function doSomething(){
     EXIT_CODE=$1
}

while(//something)
do
if [ "$EXIT_CODE" == 0 ]; then
     echo "normal exit => OK"  
     exit 0
fi
# If the exit code is not 0, then there was a error.
if [ "$EXIT_CODE" > 0 ]; then
    echo "Error => $EXIT_CODE"
    exit $EXIT_CODE 
fi
done
```

I want that the exit_code that I set in the original script, pass to the running script so this can evaluate it, and continue doing whatever has to do or EXIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of functionality, ***every*** language relies on *interprocess messaging*.
In bash it always is a bit hackish because it is not "cooked&ready".

I tried to change as little as possible to your code (did fix some syntax though).
You have the possibility now to choose your IPC mechanism: file or named pipe on ram or disk.
sockets are also possible and even the inotify kerneldaemon could be used.

This one works with a named pipe in tmpfs and with a [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

// Original script

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo "/tmp/$$" ; exec 3<>"/tmp/$$"  
doSomething() { echo "$1" >&3 ; pkill -SIGUSR1 "runningScript.sh" ;}


VALUE_OF_EXIT_CODE=256

/home/dev/runningScript.sh $arg1 $arg2 &


# some code

doSomething "$VALUE_OF_EXIT_CODE"
```

// running script

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "read EXIT_CODE <&3" SIGUSER1

while something
do
if [ $EXIT_CODE = 0 ]; then
     echo "normal exit => OK"  
     exit 0
fi
# If the exit code is not 0, then there was a error.
if [ $EXIT_CODE -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Error => $EXIT_CODE"
    exit $EXIT_CODE 
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not work that way. Here is what you should do:

1. Write the VALUE_OF_EXIT_CODE into a temporary file say tmp.
2. If you know the name of the running script's file, you can use `pidof` to get its pid.
3. Then use `kill - ' to indicate to the script that something has become available for it to do.
4. Your running script should have been coded to read from the tmp file. It should read that value and do whatever it has to do.

Yet another method would be to create a named pipe using `mkfifo`. Your running script should read from the pipe as its STDIN while your "another" script could write to it as its STDOUT.

There may be other ways of passing information between two different running bash scripts but multi-threaded programming in bash is still a long way to go.

Comment: +1 from me, because bash has indeed no precooked advanced and embedded IPC mechanisms. Indeed the dirty plumbing must be done by ourselves with pipes, files, sockets, inotify and signals...and there is no other way. We are still waiting for an implementation of POSIX message passing in bash ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way round, in my opinion. It would be easier to make what you call the "running script" start the "original script", instead of vice-versa.

Then you can read the exit code with `$?`, and call a function with it:

```
myFunction $?
```